# How to associate each item in ListView with id from database

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` object with `Adapter` extended from `CursorAdapter`. There are only `(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)` parameters in `onListItemClick()` method. I need to query my database with `_id` for currently chosen list's `item`. But I don't want the `_id` of the row from `database` to be shown in the list's row. So I created additional `TextView` in `list_item.xml` and made it invisible by setting its `width` and `height` to `0px`. So on `newView()` I can associate the list's item with it's `_id` in `database`.

I find this approach to be ugly a bit. Might be there are any other more neat solution?

Comment: umm, why do you need to "show" the _id? It need not be a part of the list at all.

Comment: but I do NOT want to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html) ViewHolder pattern which will let you set a custom object in the tag of the row. You can add the extra properties to the ViewHolder class (like _id) and set them when creating your ViewHolder objects. It will also help with performance of inflating and reusing views.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `View.setTag()` to set associate custom object with any view you return from your custom `CursorAdapter`. And then access this tag from your `onListItemClick()`.

Comment: I already use this to associate View with ViewHolder. Can I set several tags for single object?

Comment: sorry inazaruk, Just realized I answered with the same answer after you did.

Comment: @AndroidNoob, Just create a custom class that holds several objects and set instance of that class as tag. For example, `class Helper { int id; Object anotherObject; }`